# Why does Tyler Durden leave the Narrator taking his suitcase?

Tags: plot-explanation, fight-club

In the movie *Fight Club*, Tyler Durden leaves the Narrator taking his suitcase while the narrator was asleep. My question is not about the car crash, it's about the scene that comes after the car crash, when Tyler Durden leaves the Narrator while he was asleep.

I read the book Fight Club but didn't get the reason why Tyler Durden left the Narrator and later appears in the hotel room to tell the Narrator that he broke his promise of not talking about him to Marla.

I think Tyler left so that he can test the Narrator is trustworthy or not but am not sure about that.

Comment: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/32163/how-do-you-explain-the-car-crash-scene-in-fight-club?rq=1

Comment: @Rakesh_Kulkarni I should have explained my reason for the link. Yes I have watched the movie. You ask why Tyler left and then comes back etc. I liked the first answer in the link as it goes into who is in control of the physical body and mind, particularly whilst sleeping. As we are dealing with a question on multiple personalities within one individual I felt to answer this question with anything seemingly definitive would only be a subjective answer. I thought you would enjoy the thoughts of other users  who muse the workings of a fictional character suffering personality disorder.

Comment: @Rakesh_Kulkarni Please calm down a little. *YetisasquatchAlienbeliever* *never* said that this question was a duplicate of the linked question, other people did so. He merely provided an interesting link to a highly related (even if not duplicate) question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the crash Tyler takes his suitcase and leaves to set Project Mayhem in motion so it can continue without him.

He leaves sleeping Jack in the room (i.e. takes control of his body), gives specific instructions to everyone in the Paper Street Soap Company building and in other Fight Clubs around the country (hence the suitcase with tickets etc.) so that when he goes back and relinquishes Jack's body, Jack can't do anything to stop it.

That's why later we see Jack walking aimlessly around the house where everyone in was doing their part of Project Mayhem (Jack calls it "controlled chaos" or something like that). Only after Bob's death he decides to follow Tyler's trail and realizes Tyler had given specific instructions all around the country - to deny his existence of the Clubs, to spread false information about Tyler Durden, to cut balls of everyone trying to stop it (even including Tyler himself) etc.

Similarly, later after Tyler shows up in the hotel (and he does that because Jack spoke about Tyler to Marla, against his triple promise) and Jack learns the truth (that they are sharing the same body), Jack again loses his consciousness and wakes up several hours later with a phone in his hand, because Tyler has used his body to make calls to give Project the green light.